# Connecting android to remote sqlserver

Tags: java, android, sql-server, tcp

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server remote database but I can't create new connection in Android although I can connect through a Java application with exact the same code. `DriverManager.getConnection()` throws an exception. Here's my code

```
public DatabaseManipulation()
{
    URL=String.format(URL,localDatabaseName);
    Connect();
}

public void Connect() {
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,
                                   DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        statement=connection.createStatement();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("con",e.getMessage);
    }
}
```

Exception:

> "The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.100.23, port 1433 has
>   failed. Error:  "/192.168.100.23:1433 - Network is unreachable. Verify
>   the connection properties. Make  sure that an instance of SQL Server
>   is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections  at the port.
>   Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall."."

Comment: 192.168.100.23 is a private network IP address not accessible from the internet.  Is your device on the same network?  BTW, directly accessing a remote db from a mobile device poses many security and architecture issues. Did you consider having a service in front of your db to support the mobile app?

Comment: yes the devices are in the same network. I can connect with a java application on another PC with no problem but android doesn't work.

Comment: Does your app have network access permission set in `AndroidManifest.xml`? (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`)

Comment: yes and some other permissions like : Bluetooth ,Access_network_State,....

Answer (score 0):

When two or more SQL Servers are connected across network they do all communication using TCP/IP. The default port of SQL Server installation is 1433. This port can be changed through SQL Server Configuration Manager. TCP/IP should be enabled for SQL Server to be connected.

Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP

Comment: I've checked that it is on. As I told I can connect throw a java application with exact code but I have problem in android.